# How do I show that these two presentations are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I'm taking algebraic topology this year and my professor assigned a class an exercise, and he told that the exercise will be on a coming exam.

The exercise is:

> Show that $(x,y|xyx=yxy)\cong (a,b|a^2=b^3)$.

I googled it and I found this type of group is called "the Braid group".

How do I show those two presentations are isomorphic?

I asked my professor today that "Do you mean to find an explicit isomorphism between them?". Then, my professor said Yes.

How do I show they are isomorphic?

I have no idea whether there is an relatively easy way to show that..

Please help

Comment: Hint: consider the relations holding between $xyx$ and $yx$, and observe that $x=(xyx)(yx)^{-1}$ and $y=(yx)^{-1}(yxy).$

Comment: You don't show *presentations* are isomorphic --- you show the *groups* for which they are presentations are isomorphic.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, if I remember correctly, $(S|R)$ is indeed defined as a group in Rotman's "introduction to the theory of Group"

Comment: OK, but I don't see how it can be a group and be a presentation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $(S|R)$ is just the quotient of the free group $F(S)$ over the normal closure of $R$. It can be proven that every group is isomorphic to some $(S|R)$. If $G\cong (S|R)$, we say $(S|R)$ is a presentation for $G$. With this definition $(S|R)$ is a presentation for itself.

Comment: I know the math, I just never saw the terminology used that way.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Since this is the first time I'm learning about presentation, I don't know the standard way the terminology is generally used. Would you please tell me what do you precisely mean by "presentation" then?

Comment: If you're happy with the usage you've learned, don't worry if my usage is different. I'd say that, for example, $S_3$ is a group, and $\langle\,a,b\mid a^2=1,b^3=1,bab=a\,\rangle$ is a presentation (in terms of generators and relations) of the group $S_3$.